# Reference request: Caratheodory Extension Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, lebesgue-measure

I'm looking for a PDF or textbook that has a complete proof, using Caratheodory, that there is only one translation-invariant measure on $\mathbb R$ that assigns $b-a$ to intervals $(a,b)$. Most things I've seen have "left as an exercise to the reader" for certain key properties, unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A detailed proof can be found in the book "Measures, integrals and martingales" by René Schilling (Chapter 5: Uniquenuess, Chapter 6: Existence via Caratheodory). There is also a German translation ("Maß und Integral").